# GLES20.glUniform4fv and fragshader

Tags: android, kotlin, opengl-es

Okay so I'm trying to just cycle through and use multiple colors in an object but can't seem to figure it out and about to rip my hair out honestly, but this code came from Androids guides and I have been playing around with it for a minute now and have tried numerous different things but always end up going back to the question, "Is it the fragment shader, or am I just using the function GLES20.glUniform4fv(colorHandle, 2, color, 0) wrong? Why would it have a 'count' value and an array argument if it can't take an array argument of colors?"

```
class Triangle {
    private var mProgram: Int
    private var vPMatrixHandle: Int = 0
    private var positionHandle: Int = 0
    private var mColorHandle: Int = 0
    private val fragmentShaderCode: String =
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
        "uniform vec4 vColor[];\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
            "\tgl_FragColor = vColor;\n" +
        "}"
    private val vertexShaderCode: String =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;\n" +
        "void main() {\n" +
            "\tgl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;\n" +
        "}"

    private val COORDS_PER_VERTEX: Int = 3
    private var triangleCoords: FloatArray = floatArrayOf(
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f
    )
    private val color: FloatArray = floatArrayOf(
        0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f,
        0.63671875f, 0.22953125f, 0.78265625f, 1.0f
    )
    private val indiceCoords: ByteArray = byteArrayOf(
        0, 4, 5, 0, 5, 1,
        1, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2,
        2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 3,
        3, 7, 4, 3, 4, 0,
        4, 7, 6, 4, 6, 5,
        3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2
    )

    private val vertexCount: Int = triangleCoords.size / COORDS_PER_VERTEX
    private val vertexStride: Int = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4

    private var vertexBuffer: FloatBuffer =
        ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(triangleCoords.size * 4).run {
            order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
            asFloatBuffer().apply {
                put(triangleCoords)
                position(0)
            }
        }

    private var indiceBuffer: ByteBuffer =
        ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indiceCoords.size * 4).run {
            order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).apply {
                put(indiceCoords)
                position(0)
            }
        }

    init {
        val vertexShader: Int = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode)
        val fragmentShader: Int = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode)
        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram().also {
            GLES20.glAttachShader(it, vertexShader)
            GLES20.glAttachShader(it, fragmentShader)
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(it)
        }
    }

    fun loadShader(type: Int, shaderCode: String): Int {
        return GLES20.glCreateShader(type).also { shader ->
            GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode)
            GLES20.glCompileShader(shader)
        }
    }

    fun draw(mvpMatrix: FloatArray) {
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram)
        positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition").also {
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(it)
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
                it,
                COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                false,
                vertexStride,
                vertexBuffer
            )
            mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor").also { colorHandle ->
                GLES20.glUniform4fv(colorHandle, 2, color, 0)
            }
            vPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix")
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(vPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0)
            GLES20.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indiceBuffer)
            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use open sized arrays in glsl uniforms and you cannot assign an array to `gl_FragColor`. The type of `gl_FragColor` is `vec4`. If you want to associated colors to the vertices, then you've to add an additional attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to associated colors to the vertices, then you've to add an additional attribute. The number of colors has to be the same as the number of vertices.

Add a color attribute to the vertex shader (`attribute vec4 vColor;`). Pass the attribute from the vertex shader to the fragment shader (`varying vec4 color;`):

```
private val fragmentShaderCode: String =
    "precision mediump float;\n" +
    "varying vec4 color;\n" +
    "void main() {\n" +
        "\tgl_FragColor = color;\n" +
    "}"
private val vertexShaderCode: String =
    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
    "attribute vec4 vPosition;\n" +
    "attribute vec4 vColor;\n" +
    "varying vec4 color;\n" +
    "void main() {\n" +
        "\tcolor = vColor;\n" +
        "\tgl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;\n" +
    "}"
```

Define an array with 8 colors. For instance:

```
private val COORDS_PER_COLOR: Int = 4
private val color: FloatArray = floatArrayOf(
    0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f,
    0.63671875f, 0.22953125f, 0.78265625f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
)

private val colorCount: Int = color.size / COORDS_PER_COLOR
private val colorStride: Int = COORDS_PER_COLOR * 4
```

Create a buffer for the color attributes:

```
private var colorBuffer: FloatBuffer =
    ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(color.size * 4).run {
        order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
        asFloatBuffer().apply {
            put(color)
            position(0)
        }
    }
```

Specifry the array of color attributes:

```
mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vColor").also { colorHandle ->
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorHandle)
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
        colorHandle,
        COORDS_PER_COLOR,
        GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
        false,
        colorStride,
        colorBuffer
    )
}
```

Comment: And again you solved my problem! I have stumbled upon some very useful specifications at https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_gl.php which I just started reading which I would definitely recommend reading to anyone first trying to play around with OpenGL, and hopefully I really believe from these specs that I will be able to stop being so nooby here soon asking all these such nooby questions. Do you know any other guides, specs or sites you could recommend to someone unintelligent of graphics? I know Web Development through PHP Javascript and Assembly and little Kotlin as experience.

Comment: For Web and JavaScript applications, I recommend [WebGL](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0.0/) respectively [WebGL 2.0](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/). Start with [WebGL Fundamentals](https://webglfundamentals.org) and continue with [WebGL2 Fundamentals](https://webgl2fundamentals.org)  .

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use the "uniform" array (vColor[]), specify the array-size explicitly in the declaration.

```
private val fragmentShaderCode: String =
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
                "uniform vec4 vColor[2];\n" +
                "varying vec4 vParam;" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "\tgl_FragColor = vColor[int(step(vParam.x * vParam.y * vParam.z, 0.0))];\n" +
                "}"
private val vertexShaderCode: String =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
                "attribute vec4 vPosition;\n" +
                "varying vec4 vParam;" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "\tgl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;\n" +
                "\tvParam = vPosition;" +
                "}"
```